# PHP scripts not executed by cron on Linux server

Tags: php, linux, cron

I host a couple of websites which have live twitter feeds. My set up means that each website has a `tweets.php` file that will get the tweets using twitter OAUTH and then write it to a text file. I then use a javascript file to get the JSON from the raw text (.txt) file.

Until I learnt about cron jobs I was refreshing the tweets.php files myself as part of my day-to-day admin.

However, I've set up my cron jobs and they don't seem to be executing the php file or writing to the text file (both have `777` permissions on them).

Furthermore, I have both a cron file created using `crontab -e` but there is also a directory called `cron.hourly`. As I wasn't sure which one to use I have put the cron jobs in both but they don't seem to be executing. Here are my files:

```
@daily /etc/webmin/mysql/backup.pl --all
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /etc/webmin/status/monitor.pl
0 * * * * /var/www/html/websiteone.co.uk/wp-content/themes/websiteone/tweets.php
0 * * * * /var/www/html/websitetwo.co.uk/wp-content/themes/websitetwo/tweets.php
```

And the cron file (called 'twitter') within the `cron.hourly` directory is:

```
/var/www/html/websiteone.co.uk/wp-content/themes/websiteone/tweets.php
/var/www/html/websitetwo.co.uk/wp-content/themes/websitetwo/tweets.php
```

Now I've checked the cron logs and they seem to be running the jobs hourly but the tweets aren't updating and neither is the raw text file.

```
08:00:01 ip-10-142-232-156 CROND[25986]: (root) CMD (/var/www/html/websitetwo.co.uk/wp-content/themes/websitetwo/tweets.php)
Jun  5 08:00:01 ip-10-142-232-156 CROND[25987]: (root) CMD (/etc/webmin/status/monitor.pl)
Jun  5 08:00:01 ip-10-142-232-156 CROND[25988]: (root) CMD (/var/www/html/websiteone.co.uk/wp-content/themes/websiteone/tweets.php)
Jun  5 08:01:01 ip-10-142-232-156 CROND[26014]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun  5 08:01:01 ip-10-142-232-156 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[26014]: starting 0anacron
Jun  5 08:01:01 ip-10-142-232-156 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[26023]: finished 0anacron
Jun  5 08:01:01 ip-10-142-232-156 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[26014]: starting twitter
Jun  5 08:01:01 ip-10-142-232-156 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[26033]: finished twitter
```

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious but scheduled task automation is a new area for me.

Comment: Post the start of your tweets.php. It has to start with `#!/path/to/php`, otherwise the crond doesn't know HOW to execute that file.

Comment: Alternatively, use `php /path/to/the/script.php` as command in the crontab.

Comment: both above are correct there's a 3rd option I always run my php's in cron via a shell script wrapper allowing me to chain related stuff to process in certain orders + write outputs into the syslog properly rather than having to fudge a php based log write.